# Why am I not getting any bows from my mob grinder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I have a really simple grinder set up in my base. Mobs fall about 30 blocks on top of a hopper, which feeds to another hopper and finally to a chest.

But I'm not getting **any** bows from the skeletons! Any ideas why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bows only drop when the skeleton is killed by the player.

Your mob grinder kills them by fall damage, so the bows would not drop.

Comment: Note that if the mobs fall 22 blocks, they will be left with half a heart and you can kill each one with one punch. Then you have a chance to get bows as well as XP.